# Use tasks in always @* blocks

Tags: verilog

I was intended to use a customized task in an `always @*` block, like:

```
input [31:0] a;
input b;
output reg [31:0] c;

task mytask;
begin
    if (b) begin
        c = a;
    end
end
endtask

always @* begin
    // ... (b is not included)
    mytask;
    // ... (b is not included)
end
```

What I think is that when signal `b` changes from `0` to `1`, `c` will be set to the content of `a`. Then I found the `always` block is not sensitive to signal `b` (using ISim 14.7).

Is this a bug or designed to behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is specified to behave like this.  Always @* (or always_comb) blocks are not sensitive to changes in values used in tasks that are not included in the argument list.  Use a function here since your body in not consuming time.

Answer (score 1):

That is the defined behavior in Verilog. If you wan to make the task sensitive to the signals you have to put them in the I/O list:

```
task mytask(input b);
```

(And the reason I know is that I also made that error and looked it up)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answers:
Your original `always @*` procedure will never execute because it has an empty trigger list. `@ *` means: Hey tool (simulator which relies on this list), build the sensitivity list for me. `always @ *` (by the lang spec) is only sensitive to changes on the arguments of a function/task (alongside other triggers)(in your case - no arguments thus empty sensitivity list), not to changes in signals within the function/task contents.

<s>Side note: I think SystemVerilog's `always_comb` would work here (2012 std 9.2.2.2.2).</s> [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2755607/dave-59), thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `always_comb` just in-lines `function` calls, not tasks. It does this specifically so you can add debug code tasks inside an `aways_comb` without changing its sensitivity.